# Use randperm in a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

I have a matrix called "featureMatrix". using `size(featureMatrix)` the result is: 11843 720. I want to shuffle the content of this matrix using randperm. First I choose the seed using `rng(1)`. Then I use randperm: `featureMatrixRnd = featureMatrix(randperm(length(featureMatrix))');`. But it didn't work good. In fact if i write `size(featureMatrixRnd)` I obtain 11843 1, instead of 11843 720. why?

Comment: Why use length and not size or numel as input for randperm

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is the best solution:

```
rng(1);
idx = randperm(size(featureMatrix,1));
outfeatureMatrixRnd = featureMatrix(idx,:);
```

Using

```
OrgSize = size(featureMatrix);
featureMatrixRnd = randperm(numel(featureMatrix));
out = reshape(featureMatrix(featureMatrixRnd),OrgSize);
```

is not good, because I don't need to shuffle everythink independently

Comment: You asked to shuffle the entire matrix, which is what the other answers did. Changing the requirement after you posted the question is not very well received here.

Answer (score 4):

Because you used [`length`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html), which selects the longest dimension. First use [`numel`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) instead of `length` to get all elements, then [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) back to your original size:

```
OrgSize = size(featureMatrix);
featureMatrixRnd = randperm(numel(featureMatrix));
out = reshape(featureMatrix(featureMatrixRnd),OrgSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is similar to [Adriaan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43524000/5737630), but does not require a reshape:

```
featureMatrix(:) = featureMatrix(randperm(numel(featureMatrix)));
```

Comment: You'll have to initiate `featureMatrixRnd` somewhere for this, and actually index into the original `featureMatrix`.

Comment: Doesn't work in this way. The result of size is ans =

    83137860           1

Comment: @Adriaan oops, you're right, I did not notice that the output matrix had a different name then the input, I though both where named `featureMatrixRnd`... I updated the answer, but it does not really fit the question anymore since it assigns the output in to the input matrix....

Comment: What you can do, of course, is to determine `featureMatrixRnd = featureMatrix;` first and then overwrite that one the way you did. Then you do keep the original.